# IE11 wait promise result

Tags: promise, synchronization, wait

How can I wait for promise/script.onload to execute without: .then(), .catch(), await/async and callback IE11. Something comparable to the Sleep(100) on cpp. If I do a loop 'while(loadFlag == false);' and check if the flag has changed, the browser hangs and stops responding. I want to achieve something like:

```
ScriptLoad(script);
functionFromLoadedScript();
```

but i cant make this... Pls help with this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have a status flag you could use `setInterval` to poll the status.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

```js
ScriptLoad(script);
var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
    if (loadFlag === true) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        functionFromLoadedScript(); 
    }
}, 100);
```

You could also load a `Promise` polyfill library in IE so you can use `then`/`catch`.  `async`/`await` are not required.  Promises can do the same with chaining.  If you really want to use `async`/`await` you can use `TypeScript` to target `ES5`.  `TypeScript` can transpile `async`/`await` to the equivalent code using `Promise` that will run in IE.  For this to work you must target ES5 and you must load a `Promise` polyfill library in IE.

Comment: I want to pause thread execution until the flag changes. If I run setInterval in which I check the flag, the execution of the js will continue and the next expression will not wait for completion. I need exactly how to stop the thread. without situation ``onload(a){load(b)}''. When Promise is called, the code continues its execution without waiting for it to finish. I know there is await but I can't use it because it's cross-browser. You need to use only vanilla with restrictions described above.

Comment: @LEGENDAwarc if you pause thread execution, the flag will never change.

Comment: Please note "await" does not pause thread execution.  Structurally, it looks like it pauses execution -- but it does not.  The execution environment will continue to process other tasks in the thread.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.